# Show that the Maclaurin series of $f(x)=1/\sqrt{1-x}$ holds for $x\in[0,1/2]$ using the Lagrange remainder theorem

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

> Show that the Maclaurin series of $f(x)=1/\sqrt{1-x}$ holds for $x\in[0,1/2]$ using the Lagrange remainder theorem

I can see that

$$f'(x)=\frac12 (1-x)^{-\frac32}\text{ and }f''(x)=\frac12\frac32(1-x)^{-\frac52}$$

and in general

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(j-\frac12\right)}{(1-x)^{n+\frac12}}$$

Then the Maclaurin series can be written as the limit when $N\to\infty$ of

$$\mathcal M_N[f(x)]=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{x^n\prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(j-\frac12\right)}{n!}=\sum_{n= 0}^{N}x^n\prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac1{2j}\right)$$

And we can write the Lagrangian remainder as

$$\mathcal R_N[f(x)]=\frac{f^{(N+1)}(c_N)}{(N+1)!}x^{N+1}=\frac{x^{N+1}}{(1-c_N)^{N+\frac32}}\prod_{j=1}^{N+1}\left(1-\frac1{2j}\right)$$

for some $c$ such that $|c|<|x|$. Then my problem comes here: I can show, using the ratio test, that $\mathcal R_N[f(x)]$ converges for $x\in[0,1/2]$. But I think that this is not enough to show that the Maclaurin series holds on $[0,1/2]$ because the remainder must converges to zero, and I dont know how to show it.

My question: it is just enough to show that the remainder converges or I must show that it converges to zero? If it is the second case (as I think), how I can show it in this particular problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a mistake writing the formulas in the original question, now is corrected and is clear that the remainder converges to zero because the productory converges and $\left|\frac{x}{1-c_N}\right|<1$ because

$$0\le |c_N|<|x|<1/2$$

Then now we have

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\mathcal R_N[f(x)]=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{1-c_N}\right)^{N+1}\cdot \overbrace{(1-c_N)^{-\frac12}}^{<1}\cdot \overbrace{\prod_{j=1}^{N+1}\left(1-\frac1{2j}\right)}^{<1}=0$$

∎

Answer (score 2):

If the remainder term $R_N$ does not converge to $0$ then the power series will not sum to $f(x).$

For just the case $0\leq x<1/2 :\quad$ Let $x=1/2-y.$ Then $c_N$ (which you write as $c$) satisfies $1-c_N>1-x$  for every $N. $ Let $z=x/(1-x).$ Then $0\leq z<1. $

For every $N$ we have  $$0<x/(1-c_N)<z<1.$$ Note that $z$ does not depend on $N.$

Now since $0\leq z<1, $ there exists $k$ with $0<k<1$ such that for all sufficiently large $N$ we have $z(1+3/(2 N+2))<k.$ So for all sufficiently large $N$ we have $0<R_{N+1}<k R_N,$ so $R_N\to 0.$

That is, choose $N_0$ such that $n> N_0\implies z(1+3/(2 n+2))<k. $ Then for all $m> 0$  we have $0<R_{N_0+m}<k^m R_{N_0}.$

Comment: This is the generalized binomial theorem, which is valid whenever $|x|<1$, discovered by Isaac Newton, who wrote in such a difficult style that much of his math is named after others, many of whom who broadened and deepened his results, but also  wrote in a way that could be read by somebody else.  Try writing calculus and physics in the language of Euclidean geometry. Newton actually did.

Comment: I had a ugly mistake in the formula (that I already corrected) and now is clear that $\mathcal R_N$ converges.

Comment: The Taylor series for $(1-x)^{-1/2}$ converges for $|x|<1$.  The remainder term must approach zero as $N\to \infty$.  How would you proceed if $x$ were not restricted to be less than $1/2$?

Comment: @Dr.MV.  I would prefer to use another approach, without the Lagrange form. But that is not what the Q asks. I'm busy now.I'll be back.

Comment: Your answer is fine.  And I agree that this isn't the best form of the remainder to use as an estimate ... especially for $x\in (1/2,1)$

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you....I didn't see the (fairly obvious) error in the remainder term in the Q, which the OP has corrected.